# Kafka producer unable to send event and crashing

Tags: python, apache-kafka

The following kafka producer code is unable to send notifications to the broker and it throws an info that connection is being closed. I don't think there is any problem with the broker, topic or permissions to emit an event. I used Producer class from confluent_kafka and it works, so I guess its something to do with the below code using KafkaProducer. After executing the line, **producer.send(...)**, code terminates and back to the prompt which is making it difficult to figure out what is happening.

Can you please provide some pointers to debug?

```
INFO:kafka.conn:<BrokerConnection node_id=bootstrap-0 host=bootstrap-server:443 <connected> [IPv4 ('xx.xxx.xxx.xxx', 443)]>: Closing connection.
```

```
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from pathlib import Path
from kafka.errors import KafkaError
from kafka import KafkaProducer

dotenv_path = Path("./local.env")
load_dotenv(dotenv_path=dotenv_path)

import json
import logging
import os

import sys
logging.basicConfig(stream=sys.stderr, level=logging.INFO)

def main()
    try:
        bootstrap_server = os.environ['KAFKA_SERVERS']
        topic = os.environ['KAFKA_TOPIC']
        ssl_certificate_location = os.environ['SSL_CERTIFICATE_LOCATION']
        ssl_key_location = os.environ['SSL_KEY_LOCATION']
        ssl_ca_location = os.environ['SSL_CA_LOCATION']

        producer = KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers=bootstrap_server,
                                 security_protocol='SSL',
                                 ssl_check_hostname=True,
                                 ssl_cafile=ssl_ca_location,
                                 ssl_certfile=ssl_certificate_location,
                                 ssl_keyfile=ssl_key_location)

        for i in range(5):
            d = {'val': i}
            print("Iteration: ", i)
            print("Is connected to bootstrap: ", producer.bootstrap_connected())
            future_record_meta_data = producer.send(topic, value=json.dumps(d))
           
            try:
                record_metadata = future_record_meta_data.get(timeout=None)
                print(record_metadata)
            except KafkaError as e:
                print("Unable to send message [%s]" % e)

    except Exception as e:
        logging.debug("Exception ", e)
        print(e)
   
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Here is the code snippet with confluent_kafka Producer which works as expected

```
conf = {
           'bootstrap.servers': bootstrap_server,
           'security.protocol': 'SSL',
           'ssl.certificate.location': ssl_certificate_location,
           'ssl.key.location': ssl_key_location,
           'ssl.ca.location': ssl_ca_location
}
  
producer = Producer(**conf)
producer.produce(topic, payload_str)
```

Following are the version

```
python version 3.11.0
Kafka broker version 2.5.0
kafka-python==2.0.2
confluent-kafka==2.1.1
```

Comment: Kafka isn't an HTTP service. Why use port 443? Also, you don't need 2 different Kafka libraries installed

Comment: 2 libraries are not needed, this is to provide evidence that with KafkaProducer that am not able to emit events, while with confluent producer lib, am not able to emit events to Kafka as expected.

Comment: Regardless of the library used, it seems you need to connect to the proper port, not one commonly used for HTTPS